# What is the error in this python program?

Tags: python, python-2.7, while-loop

I am just recently learning to code in python. I am trying to write a program, where given integer will give an output with a root and power (range is set 5 for instance). Here is the code:

```
user_input = int (raw_input ('Enter your number: '))
root = 1
pwr = 1
def noint ():
    return 'no intergers were found'

def output ():
    return root, '^', pwr
if user_input < 1:
    print noint ()

elif user_input == 1:
    print output ()

else:
    while root < user_input:
        root = root + 1
        if root == user_input:
            print output()   
        else:
            for power in range(5):
                if root ** power == user_input:
                    pwr = power
                    print output()
```

Now, if I try 25 as an input, output is:
(5, '^', 2)
(25, '^', 2)

But if I try any prime number like 7, output is:

(7, '^', 1)

What is the problem in coding which is giving me the extra output (25, '^', 2)?

Comment: I can polish my output with this kind of code
`code` def output (): return (' %s^%s') % (str(root), str(pwr)) `code`,
but that is not the concern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want the (root, power) pair with the smallest root value possible, then:

```
try:
    while root < user_input:
        root = root + 1
        pwr = 1
        for power in range(5):
            if root ** power == user_input:
                pwr = power
                raise Found
except Found:
    print output()
```

If you want all (root, power) pairs, then:

```
while root < user_input:
    root = root + 1
    pwr = 1
    for power in range(5):
        if root ** power == user_input:
            pwr = power
            print output()
```

Comment: It is solved now. Thanks for your kind effort. Highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You're doing this:

```
while root < user_input:
    root = root + 1
    if root == user_input:
        print output()
```

That is, for `root == 24` you still enter the loop, increase it to `25`, and then you print it because `root == user_input`.

Comment: Oh, that is why, output is taking the previous pwr used in previous loop and giving me an extra output. Now I get it. Thanks man. :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here:

```
    if root == user_input:
        print output()
```

When `root == 25`, you print `output()`, but at that point, `pwr` is still `2` from when `root` was `5`, so it prints `25 ^ 2`. You have to reset `pwr` after you print `output`, or even better, use parameters instead of global variables.

You could try this (actually, there's not need for the `root == user_input` basecase):

```
def output(root, pwr):
    return root, '^', pwr

if user_input < 1:
    print noint ()
else:
    for root in range(1, user_input + 1):
        for power in range(5):
            if root ** power == user_input:
                print output(root, power)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is at this line:

```
if root == user_input:
    print output()
```

When `root` reach 25 you are printing `root` and `pwr`, but `pwr` is 2 from previous match, you have two options, update `pwr` to 1 or break the loop after the first match (as in @Synergist answer).